# Google Sign-In always returns false using gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

This is my first attempt at a Google Sign-in.  I researched much of this code.  However, in the logs, I always get: `D:/SignInActivity: handleSignInResult:false` . I get the screen to select an account, after I make a selection, nothing happens.  I tried a few answers from StackOverflow but it still does not work. So, I'm sure I'm making a dumb mistake.

**activity_test_login3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="64dp"
    tools:context="com.sinteksolutions.planningforthefuture.TestLogin3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mStatus"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/siBtn"
        android:text="Sign in"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**TestLogin3.java**

```
package xxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestLogin3 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public TextView mStatusTV;
    public Button signInBtn;
    public GoogleApiClient myGoogleApi;
    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_login3);

        mStatusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mStatus);

        signInBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.siBtn);
        signInBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Request id, email and profile
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
                .requestEmail()
                .requestIdToken("xxx")
                .build();

        //API with access to sign in
        myGoogleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(myGoogleApi);
        //Cached credentials?
        if(opr.isDone()){
            Log.d(TAG, "Cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //result from Intent
        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result){
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if(result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            mStatusTV.setText(acct.getEmail());
            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    private void signIn(){
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(myGoogleApi);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void signOut(){
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(myGoogleApi).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    private void revokeAccess(){
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(myGoogleApi).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.siBtn:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn){
        if (signedIn){
            findViewById(R.id.siBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mStatusTV.setText("Signed out");
        }
    }
}
```

**Project Gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sinteksolutions.planningforthefuture"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
}
```

JSON file in app directory.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem with SHA1 fingerprint.

Comment: I just did the SHA-1 again and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to generate a signed APK.  Running it from Android Studio does not work.

Comment: how did you fix the issue? I am having the same problem.